# Trying to disable the need for user/pass on local squid3 server

Tags: squid

I'm trying to disable the need for user/pass on my squid proxy by #-ing the following lines

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/ncsa_auth /etc/squid3/passwd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
```

but for some reason after i restart the squid service it turns unusable. 
am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

in the end i found the solution myself,
it seems all what i had to do was #-ing the following lines:

```
acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow ncsa_users
```